# Set selected cells for echarts heatmap

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using Echarts specifically ECharts. My requirement is when I click on a cell, I want to make an API call to fetch the cell details. When I select a cell, a black border is marked around the cell which means that it is selected. Also, I store the cells selected in an array. After I make API call and set the response, the component is re-rendered and the cell I selected is unselected. However, I have the selected array with me. I want to know is there a way where I can provide the selectedCells details to echarts so that it can marks those cells as selected for me. Another possibility can also be that, I store the selected cells in local storage, I pick the details from local storage and provide to echarts so that even if the user refreshes the page, the cells are still selected.